# Resource temporarily unavailable error when using git

Tags: android, git, bash

I have an important issue:
I work on a university **Jira project** on android since a few months and everything was working ok.
Since 3 days and *without reason* my git stopped to work correctly (I'm on windows), indeed now *I can't do anything*, android fail every VCS operation, from rebase, pull, to push..
I tried to git clone into another project but this always appear, at the windows cmd, git bash or even in the cygwin terminal after using a /usr/bin/rebaseall -v:

```
Cloning into 'private'...
      0 [main] bash 6952 fork: child 6924 - died waiting for dll loading, errno                    11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
1080698 [main] bash 6952 fork: child 1984 - died waiting for dll loading, errno                    11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
3140393 [main] bash 6952 fork: child 6232 - died waiting for dll loading, errno                    11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
7208694 [main] bash 6952 fork: child 5808 - died waiting for dll loading, errno                    11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
15281223 [main] bash 6952 fork: child 6408 - died waiting for dll loading, errno                    11
bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 254)
```

As it seems to deal with processus, I passed hours on the net trying to figure out the problem, but I can't manage to fix it.
I **uninstalled android studio, git, source tree, multiple times** and properly.
I used ccleaner and glary utilities to erase some old data, updated my windows, updated Comodo, rebooted many times but I still got the **Resource temporarily unavailable** error, but I can't fix it, what could I do ?

Thanks a lot for reading !

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Your system is out of memory (does not have enough RAM to run any more commands). You can reduce the number of running commands that are using up memory, or add more physical memory to your computer, or add more virtual memory backing store to allow the system to push things out to disk temporarily (but I don't use Windows and do not know how to do that on Windows).

Comment: Hi @torek thanks for your answer but I don't think it's reason why, as I have an i5 4690k as a cpu and 8Gb ram, I don't have many processus running and I never had this error since the start of the projet 4 months ago.

Comment: Ah, so it was some sort of security setting. The symptoms are pretty similar: either way the system says "no" when bash goes to load something and bash says "this might work if you try again". That suggests a flaw in the error reporting system: it should say something about security or permissions, rather than "temporary resource problem".

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to some resource limit, either on the server itself (or) specific to your user account. Limits in your shell could be checked via ulimit -a. Esp check for 'ulimit -u' max user processes, if you have reached max processes, fork is unable to create any new and failing with that error. This could also be due to swap/memory resource issue

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem !
It was due to my recent **Comodo** update which removed git from the allowed applications, so in the settings I had to do :

```
Adding Git folder to File Rating > File List as trusted file
Adding Git folder to Advanced protection > Milanescious > Shell code exclusion
Setting bit-bash.exe as allowed application in Firewall > Application Rules
```

which I found on the [Can't start Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263702/cant-start-git-bash) topic,
anyway thanks for the answers !