# GitBash for Windows DLL loading error #11

Tags: git-bash

I presume that after generating ssh keys for gitlab I broke my `Git Bash for Windows`, but may be the reason is something else I'm not sure. Reinstalling doesn't help. What can be the cause of these errors?

```
      0 [main] bash 9100 fork: child 7536 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
1087109 [main] bash 9100 fork: child 8528 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
3168945 [main] bash 9100 fork: child 7500 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
7251800 [main] bash 9100 fork: child 7328 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is here [Can't start Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263702/cant-start-git-bash)
In short - because of Comodo - strangely turning off comodo doesn't help, but adding git to trusted files, does.

Solution:

1. Add `C:\Program Files\Git` folder to Settings > File Rating > File List as trusted file
2. Add `C:\Program Files\Git` folder to Settings > Advanced protection > Milanescious > Shell code
   exclusion

[image: Comodo Advanced Settings]

Comment: "strangely turning off comodo doesn't help": yup, that thing is more toxic than a virus. Also, unchecking "detect shellcode injections", which disables the link to access the exclusions list, didn't help either.

Comment: For anyone that doesn't have Comodo and/or uses `git.exe`: the problem is git and firewalls in general - allowing `git.exe` thru the Windows Firewall worked for me.