# How to avoid died waiting for dll loading, errno 11 - Win10

Tags: windows-10, babun

I am installing Babun(http://babun.github.io/) to run tmux on Windows 10.

unfortunately, when I am updating Cygwin through update.bat file from the Babun installed folder I am getting below whole message.

While going through some other posts, people are referring to Git, etc , which I do not have anyway.

I had this working on my Win7 laptop, but in office we are forced to switch to win10.

```
     3 [main] -zsh 11180 fork: child 13276 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
/usr/local/etc/babun.start:4: fork failed: resource temporarily unavailable
/home/jchadala/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:3: command not found: env
/home/jchadala/.oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh:9: command not found: uname
/home/jchadala/.oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh:13: command not found: uname
4439101 [main] -zsh 11180 fork: child 15760 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
/home/jchadala/.oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh:18: fork failed: resource temporarily unavailable
compdump:136: command not found: mv
$fg[blue]{ dist } \
$fg[green]$(  git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null || echo ""  )$reset_color \
$fg[red]»$reset_color                                            $fg[blue]/cygdrive/c/Users/jchadala/.babun/dist$reset_color ${return_code}
```

Also if you have any other suggestions to use tmux in windows also is helpful.

Comment: any other suggestions or a resolution to me ?

Comment: Even though this is not about Git, this might've been a [firewall problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43329696/63209) (the error is the same).